# expect script not working with ssh taking input from a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, expect

I have an expect script like below.

```
/usr/bin/expect << EOD
    spawn ssh root@192.168.83.100 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 830 -s netconf < $FILE1
    expect "Password:"
    send "$PASSWD\n"
EOD
```

The ssh command does not work. It is not taking input from `$FILE1`.

What is the syntax?

#### UPDATE:

I have an expect script like below.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=/home/eorstae/mtasCDivBlackList_temp.xml
FILE1=/home/eorstae/mtasCDivBlackList.xml
PASSWD=rootroot

COUNT=0
while [ $COUNT -lt 2048 ]  
do
  sed  -e "s/VARA/${COUNT}/g" $FILE > $FILE1
  COUNT=`expr $COUNT + 1`
  /usr/bin/expect <<EOD
    spawn bash -c "ssh root@192.168.83.100 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 830 -s netconf <  $FILE1"
    expect "Password: "
    send "$PASSWD\r"
EOD

  sleep 5
done
```

**Output when running the script:**

```
[/home/eorstae] ->./myTest.sh

spawn bash -c ssh root@192.168.83.100 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 830 -s netconf <  /home/eorstae/mtasCDivBlackList.xml

Password: spawn bash -c ssh root@192.168.83.100 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 830 -s netconf <  /home/eorstae/mtasCDivBlackList.xml

Password: spawn bash -c ssh root@192.168.83.100 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 830 -s netconf <  /home/eorstae/mtasCDivBlackList.xml
```

The netconf snippet is not executed on the remote node.
Something wrong with the script.

Comment: What is the value of `$FILE1` at the line before the `expect` command?

Comment: FILE1=/home/eorstae/mtasCDivBlackList.xml

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bash -c`:

```
spawn bash -c "ssh root@192.168.1.1 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 830 -s netconf < $FILE1"
```

Comment: Or just use `sh` -- don't need any bash features for this pipeline

Comment: Just because the question is tagged with [tag:bash]. :)

Comment: insert one line `expect eof` before `EOD`